# how to use open new window with submit

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I write code on click select menu the page submitted and selected related data from database in another select menu

```html
<form method="post" name="report_localities" id="report_localities"  
      action="report_system_in_localities1.php" onsubmit="Report_locality();">

<select name="Report_Locality_State_Name" id="Report_Locality_State_Name" 
        onchange="javascript:document.report_localities.action='report_system_in_localities.php';    javascript:document.report_localities.submit();">
```

and I have another function on same page

```js
function Report_locality()
{
  document.report_localities.target = "myActionWin";
  window.open("","myActionWin","width=1000,height=500,scrollbar=yes");
  document.report_localities.submit();
}
```

when data is submitted another page open in same window I want to open another page in new window

Comment: the question isnt very clear, do you mean you want to reload the page in the same browser tab or open a new window/popup and reload the url in that?

Comment: I forced problem because I used document.form.submit() and at same time call function in form tag Report_locality() in this function use submit() I want to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1):

Just add `target="_blank"` in your form.

Comment: This correctly answers the question asked, but from the code in the question, I think the OP wants to have the results on page opened in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

add `_blank` in your javascript `window.open` parameter like

```
window.open("","myActionWin","_blank","width=1000,height=500,scrollbar=yes");
```

more [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you would like to have the results of the form submission to open specifically in the window named `myActionWin` that you create in JavaScript code. The reason why this fails is that form submission is caused by calling the `submit` method in JavaScript, rather than via a submit button. When using the `submit` method, a `submit` event is not triggered, so the `onsubmit` attribute has no effect.

The solution is to make a change in the select menu call your function, instead of directly submitting the form, i.e. to use

```
onchange=
"document.report_localities.action='report_system_in_localities.php'; Report_locality()"
```

Comment: I want to call function Report_Locality() in <form method="post" name="report_localities" id="report_localities" action="report_system_in_localities1.php" onsubmit="Report_Locality()"> in <select name="Report_Locality_State_Name" id="Report_Locality_State_Name" style="margin-top:30px;width:170px;" 
 onchange="javascript:document.report_localities.action='report_system_in_localities.php';javascript:document.report_localities.submit();"> when select menu change open new window on new tab

Comment: @SanaSana, you should clarify your question by editing question itself. In a comment to an answer, you can explain what in the answer does not work. Did you try my solution, and how does it fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: Report_Locality() call in form tag onsubmit="Report_Locality()"

Comment: As explained the answer, when you submit a form with JavaScript, the `onsubmit` attribute is ignored. So if you submit with JavaScript, you need to do whatever needs to be done in your code before calling `submit()`.

Comment: I need submitted data in form to page  called  report_system_in_localities1.php in this page select data from database when submit data equal database record and dispaly selected data in new window all this action execute when press submit button and in form call function  Report_locality() to open new window

Comment: my problem conflict between submit() in select tag <select name="Report_Locality_State_Name" id="Report_Locality_State_Name" 
onchange="javascript:document.report_localities.action='report_system_in_localities.php';javascript:document.report_localities.submit();"> and <form onsubmit="Report_Locality"> when pree submit button new window not open